# Сортировка вложенных массивов

Tags: javascript

Необходимо отсортировать массивы по числовому показателю в последнем индексе каждого массива. То есть, в массиве `mass`, в коде ниже, `mass[2]` должен оказаться на `mass[0]`, а остальные должны сместиться на 1 ступень. Пытался сделать при помощи `sort`, но особым успехом это не увенчалось.

```js
var mass = [
["Вася", "Петров", "Александрович", "10"],
["Петя", "Иванов", "Петрович", "15"],
["Владимир", "Ленин", "Ильич", "9"] ]

mass.sort(compare);

function compare(a, b){
  if (a[a.length-1] > b[b.length-1]) return 1;
  if (a[a.length-1] < b[b.length-1]) return -1;
}
console.log(mass);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сравнения необходимо приводить строку, которой представлен последний элемент массива, к числу.

В коде ниже это делается за счет `+` перед `a[a.length-1]`, ну и я слегка упростил функцию `compare`

```js
var mass = [
["Вася", "Петров", "Александрович", "10"],
["Петя", "Иванов", "Петрович", "15"],
["Владимир", "Ленин", "Ильич", "9"] ]

mass.sort(compare);

function compare(a, b){
  return +a[a.length-1] - b[b.length-1]
}
console.log(mass);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Нет мне прощения за то, что упустил весьма очевидный момент)

Comment: @barring всегда пожалуйста

Comment: А смысл унарного плюса если вычитание все равно скастует строки к числам?

Comment: @u_mulder да, его можно убрать, автоматом написал =)